# Get defferent word on string regex

Tags: c#, regex

i have here a string

```
: 0,"REC READ","+639103088703",,"15/02/14,02:04:53+32"
testing

OK
```

now i want to get just 3 word of it.

im not expert of regex patern that why i need your help.

so heres what im looking for.

in here

```
------------------------------
```

: 0,"REC READ","**+639103088703**",,"**15/02/14,02:04:53+32**"

**testing**

OK

```
------------------------------
```

how can i get this in patern? **+639103088703** and this **15/02/14,02:04:53+32** and the message **testing** on c#

Comment: What **language** and what have you **attempted** to solve this task?

Comment: ohh sorry mate. its c#

Comment: Is all that text in one string ? Have you tried using [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

Comment: Yes. i tried String.Split but i realy wanted patern in regex..